# Software Center installation Error

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

Every time I try installing Software Center on Kali Linux 2.0. it says:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  software-center : Depends: aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: python-gobject (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: python-gobject-cairo
>                    Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
>                    Recommends: gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 but it is not installable
>                    Recommends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
>                    Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

#### What this means

Essentially, this means that some programs are either not installed or are not upgraded enough.

#### What to do

To fix this you should run the command 
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install software-center`
If this does not work, then go and install/upgrade each individual dependency (e.g. `sudo apt-get install python-aptdaemon`)...